# Making a App for tablets with certain requirements

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I need to create a app that will run across Android and IOS, although i would like to avoid the native languages of both and only use JS/HTML/CSS, after digging a lot online i think that the solution would be to use Phonegap and Ionic Framework

The app is not complicated i just have to  create simple drag and drop games that the user can review at any point and make changes to them.

The whole point is for a medic to create profiles for the patients and be able to consult them at any time.

Now my question is simple: will this do enough? or should i look into anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap or Cordova are good solutions for you, then you have to build your UI with HTML. For drag & drop you could use jQueryUI

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have to go through with the PhoneGap/Cordova plugins
also, and go through with the which IDE is used for Development the Application like Xamarin,NetBeans etc.